# how does LuceneNet works & implementation feasibility for the following scenario?

Tags: azure, lucene, lucene.net, azure-storage

I am new to LuceneNet .. I should say very new. I had a few doubts in my mind which i was unable to clear after reading a lot of data regarding it. Well I am in a scenerio where I will be having huge numbers of PDFs/Docs/Excels/Images and also web pages which will be having related data to it. There are various types of users there in the system, some of them have access to the particular PDFs/Docs , some of them don't. I am to use Azure where I wish to deploy my app. So if a user searches something, I want to show him only those results, for which he is authorized to see. is it possible to do it if i use LuceneNet? Also I wish to keep a track of Hits to a particular Document/URL etc. so that it can shown in most searched etc. So is it possible to implement this using LuceneNet ? 
What things do I need to use if I want to index the files and data inside them when it comes to PDF/Doc/Docx/XSL/XSLX/PPT/PPTX etc. How should I store the data ( indexed data ) by LuceneNet ? I mean should I store it in BLOB storage? Is it advisable?? I want my application should be scalable. So will the LuceneNet support me in that? Can I have multiple instances of it's worker role? How the re-indexing can occur? Does re-indexing re-generates all indexes if so during re-indexing will I be able to search??  Sorry for so many questions together, all of them might not in proper sequence too. but I asked as I recollected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I would recommend the book called "Lucene In Action"  It is for Java, but it is on Lucene version 3.0.3, which happens to be the current Lucene.NET version..the API is the same so its a great starting resource.

To answer...
1) Is it possible to only show authorized records in Lucene.NET?  Yes..you can do it several ways.  You can seperate the indexes if you need to by user OR you can add additional fields and always include those in the search queries.

2) Yes you can keep track of hits in Lucene as well (you can keep a log of your hits and insert them as needed)

3) If you want to index PDFs, Docs, Docx...you need to extract the text.  Lucene will not do that for you.  So you can use Office Automation (for Word Docs..its free API).  The API is basic, but if you want something more mature/costs money go for AsPose (.NET libraries for doing exactly what you need)

4) There is a library that abstracts the AzureDirectory for you and uses blob storage.  I do not recommed it as it is not good for: Lucene 3.0.3, has stability problems and it uses the older Storage Client API (previous to 2.0).  I would use the Azure IaaS Virtual Machines and store the Lucene index on disks.  You can always scale and add more and stripe the disks if necessary.

5) You should have only one IndexWriter, but you can have multiple index Searchers.

6) As of Lucene 2.9.x you have something called "real-time" search, where you can have the index update and the searcher executing the queries can pick up the new data "near" real-time without the index being fully committed/flushed.

Comment: thanks a lot for a quick and prompt reply. I just want to know you are saying that you will store indexes on hard drive itself? If so say if I have only 1 VM instance, and if it goes down say azure will start another instance.. Will that instance have the same index present??or do i need to index everything again from scratch? Also same for hard drive failure?
and yeah i will look into for the book

Comment: another doubt popping up in my mind.say I hv two modules x and y.x just allows user to write something and provides facility of adding attachments.Module Y provides some common info which should be visible to all.in this scene x module should show only search results to users who have written/uploaded the docs and has typed there content. Is it possible to search accordingly in Lucene.NET index? What should be done in this scenario?And y if searched should be visible to all registered users. It will be same for all.Then how should I index data from both modules then?

Comment: Yes...for an Azure VM, you can attach data disks up to 1TB in size and you can have 16TB total.  That is plenty of storage. Data disks use Azure Blob storage, so you can back these up VERY easily by just copy/paste in CloudXPlorere or automation with the API.  If the VM goes down, what I have done is automated the data disk attachment with PowerShell..what is great is you can attach a data disk from an existing data disk (VHD).  So, if you have a backup...you can "import from" that..so your index can still be recovered if the VM goes down OR data disk failure....

Comment: Data disk disaster failure is also rare since you have 3 local copies in a data center.  You also have GeoRedundancy and 3 copies at a remote data center.  So, with that on..you would need a catastrophic failure to lose your data.

Comment: Your second question is a bit vague, but if you abstract your Lucene.NET search with a service (best practice in production)...you can handle all of the mechanisms of securing the search per user.  Lucene doesn't do security out of the box...so you have to code your business logic around it.  For example, when you create atttribute fields for whatever docs a user created...you can add those to the search behind the scenes.  For example, "User: Joe" searches for "cats".  He just types "cats" in the search box.  Your service BLL layer should pass into Lucene..search on "cats" and "user=Joe".

Comment: I am going to expose services to achieve this. Yeah I had another question popping up :D . I have some data in database which is also required to be indexed for faster searching. Is it possible to index data in DB using Lucene.net ?Is it a good choice to use Lucene.NET for the same? And in general assuming I have say 10 million docs each of 5 MB size on avg. what would be the size of lucene.net then?

Comment: It's hard to tell what the size of the index will be, but the indexes are usually smaller than the data...mine are about one third of the size, but I have a custom Analyzer I wrote for handling synonyms.  Indexing a db is great in lucene...some databases do come with search capabilities.  For example, SQL Server has full text search...but it's capabilities are limited compared to Lucene.

Comment: I wanted to know last thing..can we index data from database in lucene

Comment: Yes ANYTHING that you can turn into text you can index.  If the database has a lot of text, then that text can be streamed into an Analyzer and tokenized for search.  The process would be...use ADO.NET or some ORM and then extract the text from the databases and then send it to the Lucene.NET libraries for indexing.

Comment: thanks a lot man for helping me so much i will get back to you if I have more doubts :D